# Can Solr join tables in-memory?

Tags: performance, solr, subquery, dataimporthandler

There is a table of `n` products, and a table of features of these products. Each product has many features. Given a Solr [DataImportHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) configuration:

```
<document name="products">
  <entity name="item" query="select id, name from item">
    <field column="ID" name="id" />
    <field column="NAME" name="name" />
    <entity name="feature" 
      query="select feature_name, description from feature where item_id='${item.ID}'">
      <field name="feature_name" column="description" />
      <field name="description" column="description" />
    </entity>
  </entity>
</document>
```

Solr will run `n + 1` queries to fetch this data. `1` for the main query, `n` for the queries to fetch the features. This is inefficient for large numbers of items. Is it possible to configure Solr such that it will run these queries separately and join them in-memory instead? All rows from both tables will be fetched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using [CachedSqlEntityProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#CachedSqlEntityProcessor):

```
<document name="products">
  <entity name="item" query="select id, name from item">
    <field column="ID" name="id" />
    <field column="NAME" name="name" />
    <entity name="feature" 
        query="select item_id, feature_name, description from feature"
        cacheKey="item_id"
        cacheLookup="item.ID" 
        processor="CachedSqlEntityProcessor">
      <field name="feature_name" column="description" />
      <field name="description" column="description" />
    </entity>
  </entity>
</document>
```

Since Solr's index is 'flat', `feature_name` and `description` are not connected in any way; each `product` will have multi-valued fields for each of these.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if Solr can do this, but the database can.  Assuming that you are using MySQL, use [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html) and [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to convert this into a single query. The query should look something like this:

`SELECT id, name, GROUP_CONCAT(description) AS desc FROM item INNER JOIN feature ON (feature.item_id = item.id) GROUP BY id`

Don't forget to use the [RegexTransformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#RegexTransformer) on `desc` to separate out the multiple values.

Comment: I already use this technique for single-valued sub-entities (like tags), but how would you do this for a sub-entity with multiple fields? *I've updated the question to reflect this.*

Comment: The GROUP_CONCAT() will take all the values of description for a given id and return them in a single column of the result. Individual values of description will be separated by commas.  You can then use RegexTransformer to split by commas before indexing.

Comment: You've misunderstood what I meant. What if I have **two** fields in the sub-entity, which belong together, e.g. each product has many features, and each feature is made up of both a name *and* a description?

Comment: Not sure, maybe use GROUP_CONCAT() twice.  For example, if the feature table has a column called fname, then you could try `SELECT id, name, GROUP_CONCAT(description) AS desc, GROUP_CONCAT(fname) AS fn FROM item INNER JOIN feature ON (feature.item_id = item.id) GROUP BY id`